# BeautifulSoup doesn’t find tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup doesn’t find any tag on this page. Does anyone know what the problem can be?

I can find elements on the page with selenium, but since I have a list of pages, I don’t want to use selenium.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://dzen.ru/news/story/VMoskovskoj_oblasti_zapushhen_chat-bot_ochastichnoj_mobilizacii--b093f9a22a32ed6731e4a4ca50545831?lang=ru&from=reg_portal&fan=1&stid=fOB6O7PV5zeCUlGyzvOO&t=1664886434&persistent_id=233765704&story=90139eae-79df-5de1-9124-0d830e4d59a5&issue_tld=ru'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('h1')
```

Comment: Try to see what ends up inside the `page.text` attribute with `print()`. I bet it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the info on that page by adding headers to your requests, mimicking what you can see in Dev tools - Network tab main request to that url. Here is one way to get all links from that page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'Cookie': 'sso_checked=1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://dzen.ru/news/story/VMoskovskoj_oblasti_zapushhen_chat-bot_ochastichnoj_mobilizacii--b093f9a22a32ed6731e4a4ca50545831?lang=ru&from=reg_portal&fan=1&stid=fOB6O7PV5zeCUlGyzvOO&t=1664886434&persistent_id=233765704&story=90139eae-79df-5de1-9124-0d830e4d59a5&issue_tld=ru'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
links = [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('a')]
print(links)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
['/news', 'https://dzen.ru/news', 'https://dzen.ru/news/region/moscow', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/mobilizatsiya', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/personal_feed', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/politics', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/society', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/business', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/world', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/sport', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/incident', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/culture', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/computers', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/science', 'https://dzen.ru/news/rubric/auto', 'https://www.mosobl.kp.ru/online/news/4948743/?utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop', 'https://www.mosobl.kp.ru/online/news/4948743/?utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop', 'https://www.mosobl.kp.ru/online/news/4948743/?utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop', 'https://mosregtoday.ru/soc/v-podmoskove-zapustili-chat-bot-po-voprosam-chastichnoj-mobilizacii/?utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop', ...]
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped with my little task! I don't know what headers are, I will look into it.